# Problem with icon when changing language in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

I'm trying to create installers through Inno Setup 6.2.2 but I ran into an issue where when changing the language, the installer icon is invisible in the taskbar. This only occurs in Windows 10. And also only in the unicode versions of the inno setup. How could I solve this? The inno setup installer itself has this problem in its original installer.

I noticed that if you pass the same value to "SetupAppTitle" the problem disappears but the languages ​​have the same language value.

```
[Messages]
english.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
brazilianportuguese.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
chinesesimplified.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
french.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
german.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
italian.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
japanese.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
korean.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
polish.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
russian.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
spanish.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
thai.SetupAppTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName}
```

Comment: On Windows 10 Home 22H2 I've downloaded and executed `innosetup-6.2.2.exe`. I've selected *Deutsch* language. And the task bar button looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9N2T.png – what I believe is correct => We need [mcve].

Comment: I tested it here in the same language mentioned and it really works correctly. But by coincidence, you immediately chose one of the languages ​​that has the same value as the English language. Try another language like Japanese and you will see

Comment: With Japanese (I hope) it seems working correctly too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAk7F.png

Comment: hmm interesting. I tested on different computers with Windows 10 including the same version as yours but without success, they all had problems. Discarding variables, I imagine that perhaps there is a problem in the Windows version specific to my language (Brazilian Portuguese) as it is the only similarity I found in all the systems I tested and they had the same problem. I changed my language to Standard English United States, but the problem still persists. Maybe I should install all Windows in English to try my luck

Comment: I tested a few more times and the problem also exists on English systems. If you choose more than 3 languages ​​one at a time in the installer the error also occurs

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"choose more than 3 languages ​​one at a time"*?

Comment: select one of the languages ​​and proceed, then cancel the installation and repeat the process choosing a different language and the bug will occur

Comment: I've tried now with over 10 different languages in a row. The icon always displays.

Comment: Friend, could you help me?  Could you give me more details about your system so I can create a virtual machine and do some compatibility tests?

Comment: It's just a plain Windows 10 Home on VMware.

Comment: What is the language of the system iso?

Comment: English I guess (if it is a thing at all in Windows 10)

Comment: I TRIED USING A NEW ORIGINAL WINDOWS 10 HOME SYSTEM IN THE ENGLISH VERSION ON A VM BUT TO NO AVAIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap, the bug occurs in all versions of Windows 10, except the Home Single Language version of any language. But I found a way around using VclStylesinno.dll:

```
[Files]
Source: "D:\Repacks\Setup - Sekiro\VclStylesinno.dll"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: 
dontcopy

[Code]
// Import the LoadVCLStyle function from VclStylesInno.DLL
procedure LoadVCLStyle(VClStyleFile: String); external 
'LoadVCLStyleW@files:VclStylesInno.dll stdcall';
// Import the UnLoadVCLStyles function from VclStylesInno.DLL
procedure UnLoadVCLStyles; external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@files:VclStylesInno.dll 
stdcall';
```